# VSC C++ debugging keeps loading but never starts

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

In VSC, for a C++ program, I've configured the `launch.json` file for debuging as:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "my_target",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-ddad_fca/bazel-out/k8-dbg/bin/my_target",
            "args": [
                "input_file",
                "output_file"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/bazel-ddad_fca/bazel-out/k8-dbg/bin/my_target.runfiles/working_folder",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Skip std",
                    "text": "skip -rfu ^std::([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\<.*\>::~?\\1 *\\(",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Skip files std",
                    "text": "skip -gfi /usr/include/c++/*/bits/*.h",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/proc/self/cwd/external/": "${workspaceFolder}//external",
                "/proc/self/cwd/": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
            },
    ]
}
```

but when I launch the debug, the vsc debugger keeps initialising but never starts.

I don't know what's causing it. I've tried to reinstall C++ extensions but it did not solve my issue.

Does anyone know what it could be related to or experience the same?

[image: debugger keeps loading without starting]

Comment: you don't have a build (`preLaunchTask`) defined, do you have an exe? Does the HelloWorld example work?

Comment: it's on ubuntu!

Comment: the OS is not important, try HelloWorld example in C++ tutorial

Comment: I will try thanks, but it seems strange because other people are able to launch it anyway.

Comment: you have to follow the steps TO THE LETTER, at first I failed too

Comment: which steps? have a link?

Comment: go to the VSC doc pages and select Language/C++

Comment: I have solved by reinstalling vsc and the C++ plugins.